# Zooming into State

Tags: r, leaflet, choropleth

I am using R LeaftLet package to create a interactive choropleth of the US Map.

Now my question I want both in one map itself but make zip code visible as I zoom in a state or double click on a state.   Like If I double click on New York , the New York Zip Code opens up.  Is there a package/function in R that can help me do this?

---

Solved myself and help of others.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216819/zooming-into-state-to-view-zipcode-using-r-leaflet

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at `mapView` which is capable of doing such things. For further information, check out [this brief tutorial](https://environmentalinformatics-marburg.github.io/web-presentations/20150723_mapView.html). Say your dataset is a 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame' and the zip code is part of the referring attribute table, this can be easily done.